# Salesforce api session expired, how to reconnect automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, session, salesforce

I'm using the node module jsforce to add leads to a salesforce leads table. https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-salesforce here's the docs. The website is live at the moment but every day I'm having to restart the server as the session expires, I get this message

```
{ [INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid] name: 'INVALID_SESSION_ID', errorCode: 'INVALID_SESSION_ID' } undefined
```

here is the section of code that sets it off:

```
conn.sobject("Lead").create({
  email : req.body.email,
  firstname : req.body.first_name,
  lastname : req.body.last_name,
  title : req.body.job_title,
  company : req.body.company,
  leadsource: 'Clearing Microsite',
  description: req.body.message
}, function(err, ret) {
  if (err || !ret.success) { 
    return console.error(err, ret);
  }
console.log("Created record id : " + ret.id);
  });
});
```

I'm guessing the `return console.error(err, ret)` is what's catching the session expiring, but how can I reconnect after this occurs?

I've tried using `conn.logout` then re logging in, with the login function but couldn't get it to work and it's rather hard to test as it seems to only expire after a day!

Edit:
I think I'm needing something like `if (err == {[INVALID...]}) {reconnect}` But I just have no idea what to use

Comment: Have you moved to [JsForce](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce) like they've recommended? Since that package is no longer being maintained.

Comment: yes, I'm using jsforce, but it currently has no docs, so posted those docs as a guide

Comment: [No docs?](https://jsforce.github.io/document/)

Comment: woah they must have recently made some! alright here are the docs for jsforce: https://jsforce.github.io/document/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QwIdTab.png

This seems the right way to do it, but I'm using SOAP not OArth

Comment: There's a simple [username/password login](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#username-and-password-login) that uses SOAP by default.

Comment: yes, that's what i'm currently using, but that doesnt generate a refresh token when the session expires which is the whole problem

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to change your authentication method, if it doesn't support re-authenticating with a previous session.

Comment: yeah, i just need to work out how to find my access token and stuff in my account! I don't know how to find these things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I may have solved it, within the `if (err || !ret.success) {}` I added:

```
if (err.name == 'INVALID_SESSION_ID') {
  conn.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    conn.login(*login details*)
      // then repeated the lead entry
  });
}
```

I cant check to see if this works until tomorrow morning when the session times out, but will update if it does work / doesn't

Edit:
Didn't work, going to try without the logout. got this error

```
[Error: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key: <KEY> This is expected, it can happen if the session has expired and swept away, or if the user logs out, or if its just someone trying to hack in. ]
```

Second Edit: Taking out the logout worked like a charm! Thanks @superfell

Comment: BTW, if the session expired, then calling logout shouldn't be needed.